# Newtonsoft JSON Deserialist into list of Type

Tags: c#, json, list, types

I am dealing with JSON returned from an API, and am trying to compress the code required to deserialise it.

for a single record,

im passing in an "object", ReturnOBJ.

```
public object getAPIRecord(object returnOBJ, string recordReference)
{
string TypeName = ReturnOBJ.GetType().ToString();
Type t = Type.GetType(TypeName);
//code getting string back from API
returnObject = JSONConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONfromAPI, t);
return returnObject;
}
```

the above works, in a function returning an Object, which i'm then casting into what i need in my functional code.

I'm calling the above as:

```
ContentClass newContent = new ContentClass();
newContent = (ContentClass)getAPIRecord(newContent, "WC/123");
```

so the function is deriving "ContentClass" as the type from the object passed in.

however, if the JSON coming back is returning a list/array of type "t", how do i get it to work?

my brain was thinking something along the lines of

```
List<object> returns = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONfromAPI, List<t>);
```

but it flags the List as "not valid in the given context".

i'm guessing my List could also be wrong.  I'm not used to working with Type at all, but im trying to streamline my code for handling API responses.

i'd like to be able to call it such:

```
List<ContentClass> newlistOfContent = new List<ContentClass>();
newlistOfContent = getListofAPIRecords(newListOfContent, APIPArameters);
```

what do i need to do to morph my single record return into a List return?

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONfromAPI, typeof(List<>))`  or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(JSONfromAPI)`?

Comment: Roman, the 2nd option is the closes i've got (and tried that already, but good to know im thinking on the right lines) in that
```
List<object> returns = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<t>>(JSONfromAPI);
``` 
at least only hangs on "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<t>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'
but then i can't create the list seperately as List<t> as it complains i'm using a variable like a type. (which is what it is)

Comment: declare `returns` variable like `List<T> returns` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>`

Comment: Roman, alas that either complains that the list types don't match, or again complains that the T is being used as a variable.  At the moment i've got some code returning an IList, but now i can't convert that into a list of <ContentClass> so damned either way.